# prove that the bisector of any angle exist and is unique.

Tags: plane-geometry

This question from college geometry-discovery approach written by  Kay, David C. I don't know how can I prove that question. Could you help me please?

Comment: No it is not unique.  There are always two angular bisectors for any angle on a Euclidean plane.

Comment: What exactly is the definition of angle bisector that you're working with? The above comment by @Batominovski makes sense if the angle bisector is a ray, but if it's a line, then it should be unique.

Comment: The body of your Question should be self-contained and not wholly dependent on the title for stating the problem.   Be generous with your Readers and use enough notation so that the problem can be addressed by reasoned mathematical argument.  For example what is the angle defined by (as G Tony Jacobs asks)?